# Probability of Bankruptcy Dice game

Tags: probability

I have 10,000 dollars.
I roll a 64 sided die and if I land on 64 I win 80000 dollars. I am paying 500 dollars to play this game. My question is what is the chance I go broke?

- 1/64 to win, so I know that to lose all my money from the start is (63/64)^20 since I need to lose 20 times in a row.
- I realise this doesn't actually account for the times I win a roll then end up losing anyway

So what is the correct method of figuring out the probability of bankruptcy?

Comment: When do you stop playing?

Comment: @JMoravitz I suspect the OP will only stop if bankruptcy forces him/her to stop. There is a positive probability that this will not happen.

Comment: You can get a range of the possibility of bankruptcy - as you said there's the possibility of bankruptcy at the start = (63/64)^20 (=0.72981285599 which is pretty high). If you don't bankrupt, you have at least 80,000 after those 20 throws - 80,000 gives you another 160 throws so the chance of bankruptcy on throws 21 to 180 is less than (1-.72981285599) * (63/64)^160 ~ .021. Then you can repeat that logic and see what you come up with.

It's not exact but will give a range.